# Using wp_get_image_editor in a standalone script

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, images

With WP 3.5, they updated the image resizing scripts with `wp_get_image_editor`.

Currently, in this standalone script that is accessed with Ajax, I have included `wp-load.php` so I can access all of the WP functions.  Particularly, `$wpdb;`.  In order to use the `$wpdb` functions, I had to declare `global $wpdb;` first.

I assumed I had to do the same for `wp_get_image_editor`, but there is no global variable to declare.

When using:

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor($current);

//if (!is_wp_error($image)) {
    $image->resize(100, 100, false); }
```

nothing happens, and if I remove the `if` statement, I get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WP_Error::resize()

Does anyone know how I can do this?  Would it be smarter to install my own image-resizing scripts?

Comment: Why not use WordPress' [built-in AJAX functionality](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: I'm using FineUploader to upload the images, and it uses the ajax, but it is a very complex plugin. I don't know how to convert it to Wordpress's built in ajax.

Comment: WordPress also has a built-in image uploader (based on PLUpload).

Comment: I know!  I first tried to modify their image uploader, but it proved very difficult.  I needed to upload images and send them to select locations in the uploads folder, based on the user settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I'm just silly.

WP_Error was the undefined method, not resize.  I was sending a bad image location through the resize function.  How silly of me! It was working all along.

I've included this on top

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

and this is my image resize function

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor($current);

    if (!is_wp_error($image)) {
        $image->resize(100, 100, false);
        $image->save($target);
        return "succ";
    } else return "error";
```